# DTE.SolutionBuild not building project

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, visual-studio-extensions, csproj

im trying to build a csproj in a Visual Studio Extension (.vsix) using the DTE.SolutionBuild interface:

```
private void BuildProject(Project vsProject)
{
        var sb = vsProject.DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild as SolutionBuild;
        sb.SolutionConfigurations.Item(1).Activate();
        sb.BuildProject(sb.SolutionConfigurations.Item(1).Name, vsProject.UniqueName, true);
}
```

But for some reason, the project did not compiled. No errors are showed, a folder with the name of the SolutionConfiguration is created, but the project assemblies are not generated. Any help is apreciated.

UPDATE1: I tried this too and the result are the same:

```
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project p = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(vsProject.FullName);
p.Build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this way:

```
private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

    _SelectedObject = this.GetProjectItem();
    _VsProject = _SelectedObject.ContainingProject;
    this.BuildProject(_VsProject);
}

private void BuildProject(EnvDTE.Project vsProject)
{
    DTE2 dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as DTE2;
    dte.Events.BuildEvents.OnBuildDone -= BuildEvents_OnBuildDone;
    dte.Events.BuildEvents.OnBuildDone += BuildEvents_OnBuildDone;
    dte.ExecuteCommand("Build.RebuildSolution");
}

private void BuildEvents_OnBuildDone(vsBuildScope Scope, vsBuildAction Action)
{
    //Your action after build here
}
```